Como cambiar el nombre de APP de android studio dinamicamente?
Como cambiar el nombre de APP de android studio dinamicamente?
Buenas, tengo una APP la cual funciona para varios clientes y quiero cambiar el nombre de la APP dinamicante(con codigo Java)
Se podrá?

¿Qué entiendes por nombre de la App? Las aplicaciones deben tener un identificador único en Play Store.

en androidManifest tengo android:label="miApp" ...y en las actionBar de las activities no quiero que aparezca "miApp" como titulo, ya que tengo realizada una sola app que le vendo a varios clientes

deseo que aparezca el nombre de la empresa de mi cliente(gaurdado en Mysql)

No tienes que cambiarlo en el Manifest, puedes guardar el nombre de cada cliente en la base de datos de Android y mostrar el dato en la action bar o donde sea (la BD de Android es Sqlite, no Mysql y se recomienda usar Room para interactuar con ella). Inicialmente tú puedes pedir al cliente que registre su nombre en la BD. Y eventualmente puedes darle posibilidad de cambiarlo, cosa que no puedes hacer dinámicamente si usas el nombre de la App, aparte de tener que publicar una App por cada cliente en Play Store.
